# ¿En que influye poner '*' delante de una variable?

Tags: c, memoria

Sé que '*' se usa para definir un puntero en el momento de crear una variable, por ejemplo:

```
objeto* variable;
```

Pero, en este caso de un ejercicio de la universidad:

```
function_init(tPopularity* object) {
    tPopularity newPopu;

    /*Relleno de de datos, no importante para la pregunta*/

     object=&newPopu;
}
```

Mi idea inicial era dejar es la de arriba, es decir :

```
 object=&newPopu;
```

El problema es que al salir de la función los datos del objeto se perdían, así que lo que he hecho, sin saber muy bien por qué  es:

```
 *object=newPopu;
```

¡Y funciona! Mis datos no se pierden y los test pasan correctamente... ahora mi pregunta es.. ¿Por qué ahora mis resultados son los esperados? ¿Por qué se corrompían los datos y por qué ahora no? ¿Qué supone en mi código ese asterisco delante de una asignación?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Por qué se corrompían los datos y por qué ahora no?

Si usamos variables se ve mejor:

```
void func(int var)
{
  var = 10;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func(a);
  std::cout << a;
}
```

Da igual las veces que ejecutes el código anterior que **siempre** va a imprimir `0` y el motivo es muy simple: `var` es **una copia** de `a`, luego los cambios que realicemos sobre `var` no tendrán su eco en `var`. Es como clonar una oveja... esquilar al clon no va a hacer que la oveja original se esquile automáticamente.

Ahora vamos a ver el mismo ejemplo pero con punteros:

```
void func(int * var)
{
  int n = 10;
  var = &n;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  int* ptr = &a;
  func(ptr);
  std::cout << a;
}
```

El programa imprime otra vez `0`... ¡Pero si estamos usando punteros! ... ya, pero al igual que en el caso anterior, `var` es **una copia** de `ptr`. Lo único que comparten ambos punteros es que apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria, pero siguen siendo variables independientes.

Y aquí es donde entra en acción *el truco*. Lo que hace `var=10` es **modificar la dirección apuntada por `var`**. Tras este cambio, `ptr` apuntará a una dirección de memoria y `a` a otra diferente.

Ahora, en cambio, imagína que cambiamos un poco el ejemplo:

```
void func(int * var)
{
  int n = 10;
  *var = n;
}
```

Ahora el programa, por arte de magia, imprimrá un 10!!!

¿Qué ha pasado ahora?

Lo que sucede ahora es que, gracias al uso del asterisco, estamos modificando la **memoria compartida** por ambos punteros, `var` y `ptr`.

Es por ello qu este cambio se *propaga* fuera de la función.

Dicho esto aprovecho para aclarar un pequeño detalle: En tu primer caso no se es que se corrompiesen los datos... es que **no estabas modificando la memoria original**, la cual quedaba sin cambios tal cual estaba cuando se llamó a la función.

Comment: Me ha encantado lo de la oveja, me lo apunto :)

Answer (score 6):

¿Por qué se corrompían los datos y por qué ahora no?

Los datos se corrompían debido a que en tu `function_init` estabas asignando la dirección de memoria de la variable `newPopu` al puntero `object`, el contenido de esa dirección era apuntado por ambas variables, pero al salir de la función ese contenido se eliminaba al igual que `newPopu` y por lo tanto `object` no apuntaba a los datos que esperabas. Cuando haces `*object = newPopu` estas asignando el contenido de la variable y no la dirección de memoria en la que se encuentra, entonces tienes dos referencias a ese contenido, uno es `object` y otro es `newPopu`, cuando sales de la función `newPopu` deja de existir pero `object` sigue apuntando a una dirección de memoria que contiene el valor que se asigno dentro de la función `function_init`

¿Qué supone en mi código ese asterisco delante de una asignación?

Ese asterisco indica que vas a acceder al contenido en la dirección de memoria que es apuntada por tu variable, en este caso `object`.

Answer (score 4):

Imaginemos lo siguiente:

```
 typedef struct
 {
     int a;
     int b;
 }tPopularity;

void function_init(tPopularity* object) 
 {
    tPopularity newPopu = {1, 2};
    object = &newPopu;
}
```

Asumamos las direcciones de memoria que tendrá nuestro bloque de memoria (este bloque básicamente es donde estarán almacenados los miembros `a` y `b`) al que apunta el puntero implícito `newPopu` (del `function_init`).

```
--> Bloque A:
(a)   (b)     
0x4 - 0x8     
//El puntero implícito newPopu apunta a la dirección 0x4.
```

Ahora, con estos datos, comencemos viendo como funciona la siguiente línea:

```
object = &newPopu;
```

Estamos claro que esta instrucción es equivalente a esto:

```
object = &newPopu.a;
```

Lo que estás asignando al puntero `object` (en este caso `0x4`) es la primera dirección de memoria (en este caso `0x4`) del bloque A al que apunta `newPopu`, pero luego nos damos cuenta que el puntero `object` es un parámetro y que posteriormente, cuando la función `function_init` termine su ejecución, el espacio de memoria donde está alojado el puntero `object`, será liberado del programa y también el bloque A. En pocas palabras, tu función hizo que pierda toda la información que tenga el bloque A y esa es la razón del porqué sucede la corrupción de datos.

Ahora la solución a este problema, es la que propusiste:

```
*object = newPopu;
```

Ahora agregaré un pequeño código para reflejar el porque:

```
int main(void)
{
    tPopularity ob;
    function_init(&ob);
    printf("%d %d\n", ob.a, ob.b);
    //Resultado por pantalla: 1 2
    return 0;
}
```

Este simple código lo que hace es copiar todos los datos que tiene el objeto (al que apunta `newPopu`) hacia el objeto que apunta `ob` (del `main`).

Y para que quede más claro esto, el código:

```
*object = newPopu;
```

Es equivalente a :

```
object-> a = newPopu.a;
object-> b = newPopu.b;
```

Y con esto comprobamos del **PORQUÉ** no ocurre una corrupción de datos.

Espero que te sirva mi explicación! Saludos!